# Find value in a BehaviourSubject array, otherwise make a call

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to figure out what is the best way to execute following approch.

Search the BehaviourSubject array for a value by ID; if the value exist return it as observable, otherwise if it doesn't exist, then make a call to retrieve it from server. Once data is retrieved from server the BehaviourSubject array is updated to add the missing value.

```
private _carList = new BehaviorSubject<any[] | null>(null);
carList$ = this._carList.asObservable();

getById(id: string) {
    var value = this._carList.value?.find(r => r.id === id);
    return value ? of(value) : this.getCarDataFromServer(id);
}
```

This seems like a inefficient/unclean way of doing it, would appreciate if there is a better way to execute this.

**EDIT 1:**

getCarDataFromServer gets the data from server, returns the observable and in parallel updates _carList BehaviourSubject.

Comment: It really depends on what you want to do with the result. Do you want to add it to the array or just return it?

Comment: @martin both,  I want to see if the data exists in BehaviourSubject array and return it, otherwise get it from server and update the BehaviourSubject array.
I've added explanation of how getCarDataFromServer operates.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a this BehaviorSubject in loaderService and then call it from the loaderService. And also .next() the latest getCarDataFromServer in the subject.